# Calling several of the same component in Modelica

Tags: modelica

I seem to struggle with a modeling problem in Modelica (using Dymola), and I hereby seek your help. The idea is this:

I have modeled some components (models) that I want to connect together through their ports. The models are working. The thing is I want to connect several of the same unit (called myUnit in the pseudo code below) in a series. If the number of units were, let's say, only 5 then I could easily dragged them out 1-by-1 and connected them in a standard manner, but let's say I want 100 units. Is there an easy and elegant way to do this? I don't believe for loops to be working outside the equation part of the model, and I want an elegant way of naming the units. I'll try to illustrate this by doing a pseudo code below, explaining what I wish to achieve:

```
model someModel
    parameter Integer n = 100 "Length of series";
    parameter Real optionValue = 123;
    myLibrary.myStartUnit startUnit(someOption = optionValue); // First unit
    for i in 2:n-1 loop
        myLibrary.myUnit unit_'num2str(i)'(someOption = optionValue); // i'th unit
    end for;
    myLibrary.myEndUnit endUnit(someOption = optionValue);     // Last unit
equation
    connect(startUnit.outPort,unit_1.inPort);
    for i in 2:n-1 loop
        connect(unit_'num2str(i)'.outPort,unit_'num2str(i+1)'.inPort)
    end for;
    connect(unit_'num2str(n-1)'.outPort,endUnit.inport);
end someModel;
```

I hope I've managed to explain my problem properly, now.

Any tips for solving this problem? I greatly appreciate both strategic advice as to solve the problem as well as purely syntactic advice.
In advance, thanks for all help. :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Note that we don't include signatures or greetings in our posts in order to keep things concise (see the FAQ). Hence I've removed your greetings from the post (editing other people's posts is encouraged over here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use arrays to achieve this. For example, using models of the Modelica standard library:

```
model ArrayDemo

  parameter Integer n = 10 "Number of springs/masses";

  Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.ConstantForce constantForce(f_constant=100);
  Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Components.Spring springs[n];
  Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Components.Mass masses[n];
  Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Components.Fixed fixed;

equation 
  connect(constantForce.flange, springs[1].flange_a);
  for i in 1 : n - 1 loop
    connect(springs[i].flange_b, masses[i].flange_a);
    connect(masses[i].flange_b, springs[i + 1].flange_a);
  end for;
  connect(springs[n].flange_b, masses[n].flange_a);
  connect(masses[n].flange_b, fixed.flange);

 end ArrayDemo;
```

The idea is to declare the components using arrays and then connect them using `for` loops.

Comment: Thanks! This was of great help!

Comment: @user2527335: Glad that I could help you. If this solved your problem, please [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (click on the check mark next to it). This marks the question as solved (and rewards the poster of the answer).